# Wordpress Loop, Add specific class to the 2nd post, 3rd, reset, add class etc

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, while-loop

Im trying to custom a custom post type and change the output depending on the the order the posts.  I have the following below but the order output is working just right

The output looks like this (it skips around after the first 3 posts):

- John Doe, Vintage Burbank 8
- John Doe, Vintage Burbank 7 two
- John Doe, Vintage Burbank 6 three
- John Doe, Vintage Burbank 5 two
- John Doe, Vintage Burbank 4
- John Doe, Vintage Burbank 3 three
- John Doe, Vintage Burbank 2
- John Doe, Vintage Burbank 1 two

I want it to come out like this:

- John Doe, Vintage Burbank 8
- John Doe, Vintage Burbank 7 two
- John Doe, Vintage Burbank 6 three
- John Doe, Vintage Burbank 5
- John Doe, Vintage Burbank 4 two
- John Doe, Vintage Burbank 3 three
- John Doe, Vintage Burbank 2
- John Doe, Vintage Burbank 1 two

  ```
      <?php
      $args = array(            
        'post_type' => 'testimonials',
        'posts_per_page' => -1
      );

      $query = query_posts($args);

  ?>
  <?php  $i = 1; while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

       <?php if($i%3 == 0) : ?>

              <?php the_title();?> three

          <?php elseif($i%2 == 0) : ?>    

              <?php the_title();?> two

          <?php else : ?>

              <?php the_title();?> 

          <?php endif; ?>
          <?php $i++; ?>

  <?php endwhile;?>
  <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
  ```

Comment: Please use `if(){ }` rather than that horrible `if(): endif` thing. It makes it a billion times easier to read. Also every line does not require closing and reopening the PHP tag. You only do that if you are switching to outputting hardcoded HTML/JS.

Comment: @acontell if the posts came out 3 at a time, the 2nd one would always be marked 2, and so forth.  So if I output all of them and there's 11 posts.  The 2nd, 5th, 8th, 11th would all be marked 2

Comment: @RMH Ok, thanks, I think I grasp the idea. I've posted an answer, I think it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think your code is ok, the only problem is that you're updating `$i` badly. I've modified your code and I think it should work (let me know if it doesn't).

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'testimonials',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
);

$query = query_posts($args);
?>
<?php $i = 1;
while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php if ($i % 3 == 0) : ?>

        <?php the_title(); ?> three

    <?php elseif ($i % 2 == 0) : ?>    

        <?php the_title(); ?> two

    <?php else : ?>

        <?php the_title(); ?> 

    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php  /* Comment this line */ ?>
    <?php /* $i++; */?>
    <?php /* Add this one */ ?>
    <?php $i = ($i >= 3) ? 1 : ($i + 1); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using  everywhere? Also you need to reset $i when you get a match and it should work. Try this:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'testimonials',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
);

$posts = get_posts($args);
$i = 1;
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    setup_postdata($post);
    if($i%3 == 0) {
        echo get_the_title().' three';
        $i = 0;
    }
    elseif($i%2 == 0) {
        echo get_the_title().' two';
        $i = 0;
    }
    else {
        the_title();
    }
    $i++;
}
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```